# TortoiseSVN with ASP.net Web Projects - How to manage this?

Tags: asp.net, tortoisesvn

We're a small team starting to use TortiseSVN to manage our web projects.
I was just wondering what is the best way to manage web projects into Subversion.
As you know a web solution consists of the .sln file as well as all the .aspx files.

Well we noticed when we right click the solution and we select "Add selected projects to subversion".  It prompts me to tell it where to store the .sln file.  So I give it some path like svn://serverName/CIS/MyWebSiteProject.  Cool it just placed the .sln file...so I thought to myself how is it going to store the .aspx files as well.

Within a second I got a second prompt, I thought cool it is prompting me for the .aspx pages.  So I tried giving it the path svn://serverName/CIS/MyWebSiteProject/ASPX_Files, but it comes back with an error stating I cannot place this folder within this path.  I actually have to go outside of the folder MyWebSiteProject.

Not good cause now I have 2 folders one with the .sln folder and the other with all the .aspx pages and these folders are sitting on:

- (sln file):
  svn://serverName/CIS/MyWebSiteProject
- (aspx files):
  svn://serverName/cis/myWebSitePages

This really is not ideal cause I am sitting on the root of CIS with 2 folders for really one solution.  Now when I try to check the project out I have to check both folders out.

What makes this even worse is when I do check them out I try to open the .sln file and I get an error that it cannot find the corresponding .aspx files.  This seems like too much work, is there an easier way or a recommended way of using tortisesvn/subversion with asp.net web projects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to successfully using Visual Studio with any source control is to put the solution file in the same path as the rest of the project files.

Usually, I will do something like the following:

```
\Project\Project.sln
\Project\MainWebSite\*.*  <-- All web site files (including .??proj here).
\Project\Library\*.*
```

Then, I manually put `\Project\*.*` into source control.

Other options exist, as for my recent projects, I have been using:

```
\Project\SolutionFiles\Project.sln
\Project\MainWebSite\*.*
\Project\Library\*.*
```

Again, I manually put `\Project\*.*` into source control.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing so I like this answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

While I am sure you have TortoiseSVN installed, it sounds like you are using Ahnk or some other VS SCC plugin to add from within VS.

I would suggest not using the plugin to initally add the solution to SVN, but to use TortoiseSVN in Windows Explorer for your initial check in. This will add your solution directory in its original state.

From that point on, you should be able to use the SCC plugin from within VS without trouble.

**EDIT**

Ok, after your commment I realize that I was not fully understanding the problem.

If you are dealing with a single project, after you create your solution and project, select the solution in Solution Explorer, go to 'file>save solution as' and save the solution inside the directory where your project file is.

Close the solution and go out to Explorer and use Tortoise to add the directory to SVN. If you have multiple projects/sites, just pick one to hold the solution.

Does that make sense? and from that point you should have no problems with ahnk

Comment: Yes we are using Ahnk, but the web files are usually seperate from the .sln file when we create a web project.  Is it best to change the path to keep them all in the same directory and then use TortiseSVN to add them to the repository ?

Answer (score 0):

I generally find that it is better to set up the repositories for my solutions and projects from within Tortoise SVN. Then use whatever VS plugin that you care for to manage the commits of your pages etc. This gives you a little more control and allows you to get your setup correct from the start.

Comment: Actually, you would setup your solution and project from within VS and then do the initial add from Explorer with Tortoise.  But I know what you mean - see my answer ;-)